# Python SOAPpy Errors

Tags: python, soappy

Below is my Python code:

**Service part**

```
class Test:
    def hello():
        return "Hello World"
```

**Server Part**

```
import SOAPpy
from first_SOAP import *

host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 5551
SOAPpy.Config.debug = 1
server = SOAPpy.SOAPServer((host, port))
server.registerKWFunction(Test.hello)
print "Server Runing"

server.serve_forever(
```

**Client part**

```
import SOAPpy
SOAPpy.Config.debug = 1
server = SOAPpy.SOAPProxy("http://127.0.0.1:5551/")
print server.Test.hello()
```

This the error that I'm getting:

```
*** Outgoing HTTP headers **********************************************
POST / HTTP/1.0
Host: 127.0.0.1:5551
User-agent: SOAPpy 0.12.0 (http://pywebsvcs.sf.net)
Content-type: text/xml; charset="UTF-8"
Content-length: 350
SOAPAction: "Test.hello"
************************************************************************
*** Outgoing SOAP ******************************************************
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
  SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
  xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
  xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<Test.hello SOAP-ENC:root="1">
</Test.hello>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
************************************************************************
code= 500
msg= Internal Server Error
headers= Server: <a href="http://pywebsvcs.sf.net">SOAPpy 0.12.0</a> (Python 2.5.2)
Date: Mon, 27 Jul 2009 07:25:40 GMT
Content-type: text/xml; charset="UTF-8"
Content-length: 674

content-type= text/xml; charset="UTF-8"
data= <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
  SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
  xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema"
>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<SOAP-ENV:Fault SOAP-ENC:root="1">
<faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
<faultstring>Method Not Found</faultstring>
<detail xsi:type="xsd:string">Test.hello : &lt;type 'exceptions.KeyError'&gt; None &lt;traceback object at 0x9fbcb44&gt;</detail>
</SOAP-ENV:Fault>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

*** Incoming HTTP headers **********************************************
HTTP/1.? 500 Internal Server Error
Server: <a href="http://pywebsvcs.sf.net">SOAPpy 0.12.0</a> (Python 2.5.2)
Date: Mon, 27 Jul 2009 07:25:40 GMT
Content-type: text/xml; charset="UTF-8"
Content-length: 674
************************************************************************
*** Incoming SOAP ******************************************************
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope
  SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
  xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema"
>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<SOAP-ENV:Fault SOAP-ENC:root="1">
<faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
<faultstring>Method Not Found</faultstring>
<detail xsi:type="xsd:string">Test.hello : &lt;type 'exceptions.KeyError'&gt; None &lt;traceback object at 0x9fbcb44&gt;</detail>
</SOAP-ENV:Fault>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
************************************************************************
<Fault SOAP-ENV:Client: Method Not Found: Test.hello : <type 'exceptions.KeyError'> None <traceback object at 0x9fbcb44>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rajaneesh/workspace/raju/src/call.py", line 4, in <module>
    print server.Test.hello()
  File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.5/SOAPpy/Client.py", line 470, in __call__
    return self.__r_call(*args, **kw)
  File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.5/SOAPpy/Client.py", line 492, in __r_call
    self.__hd, self.__ma)
  File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.5/SOAPpy/Client.py", line 406, in __call
    raise p
SOAPpy.Types.faultType: <Fault SOAP-ENV:Client: Method Not Found: Test.hello : <type 'exceptions.KeyError'> None <traceback object at 0x9fbcb44>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want to make test() a class method? I suggest you change your code like this.

```
class Test:
  def hello(self):
    return "Hello World"
```

Then you must create an instance of the Test class and register:

```
server.registerObject(Test())
```

Then the client can access the hello() method like this:

```
print server.hello()
```

Comment: please tell me if any other good method .. i am beginner now . i am learning python now .. please suggest me ... which book i can read

Comment: What kind of book are you looking for? For general introductions there are "Programming in Python 3" by Mark Summerfield, "Beginning Python: From Novice to Professional" by Magnus Lie Hetland, and more.

Comment: class Test:

    def __init__(self,initdata):

        if initdata['style'] == 'FileDetails':
            self.host = initdata['host']
            self.usr = initdata['usr']
            self.pwd = initdata['pwd']
            self.database = initdata['database']
            self.sql = initdata['sql']
            self.path = initdata['path']

    def hello(self):
        return "Hello World"

now i change my code 
i want argument should be client how to do that

Comment: server.registerObject(Test(data))

Comment: data should send  client ... how to do that

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not that familiar with SOAPpy. BTW, SOAPpy is years old. I recommend suds: https://fedorahosted.org/suds/